# how do I increase exposure before taking photo in opencv?

Tags: camera, opencv, image, c++

I wrote a program in C++, using wiring pi for the LED, trigger, ad openCV3.2 for the camera. It works, taking a photo, when the button is pressed, but the photo quality is low, even in a well lit room. I think this is because the exposure time is too short.

How can I increase the exposure time, to produce higher quality images?

here is my source, from the function that needs help:

```
...
void imgGet(){

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,1); 
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    string fileName = getFName(); //returns a string for file naming
    imwrite(fileName, frame);
    }
 ...
```

The VideoCapture documentation is [here:](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)
   but the program returns

> VIDIOC_S_CTRL: Invalid argument

it takes the photo, but the exposure time never changes.

Here is an example of what I'm experiencing (both are taken without flash):
This is the image quality after running my program:
[image]

This image is from another OpenCV program, that streams Video. The image becomes saturated as I expect, because the camera is on for a longer period of time. This is a side effect of the video streaming continuously. What I want to do is control it.

[image]

Comment: In what  aspect is the image quality low? What is the purpose of the led, is it used as a flash?

Comment: The exposure is low. The camera needs to be active for a longer period, before saving the data from the camera.

Comment: Go and look at the OpenCV documentation on how to control exposure time.

Comment: What camera are you using? Not all cameras support all openCV options.

Comment: one camera is a Suyin Corp. Acer CrystalEye Webcam
the other is a Lenovo Integrated Webcam [R5U877]

Comment: It seems the CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE valid values are camera-dependent,  what other values than 1 have you tried? Have you tried changing any other CAP_PROP_* settings to see how the camera/OpenCV reacts to those settings? Such as gain or brightness?

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure some captures parameters through v4l2-ctl.
My camera don't have exposure setting, but the one you use may have it.

Run in the console :

```
v4l2-ctl -l
```

to retrieve the parameters you can change, then run

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=contrast=36
```

to define new values.

I use this approach to correct a too dark camera, successfully :)